# spark submit with python on windows- An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, master-slave

I am new to spark and I tried to submit my first job. 
The code is in python and i am running on windows 10.

On one console I deployed the master as:

```
 spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

On another I deployed one slave:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.1.4:7077
```

All good so far. 
When I want to deploy the spark job in python I run on another console the following:

```
spark-submit --master spark://192.168.1.4:7077 "C:\path\to\file\friends-by-age.py"
```

The job is executed correctly because it prints all the results well, but then an error is thrown:

```
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.1.4:4040
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
19/07/28 21:51:52 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /192.168.1.4:59096
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1106)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
19/07/28 21:51:52 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

This is the friends-by-age.py code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("FriendsByAge")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    age = int(fields[2])
    numFriends = int(fields[3])
    return (age, numFriends)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///C:/path/to/file/fakefriends.csv")
rdd = lines.map(parseLine)
totalsByAge = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
averagesByAge = totalsByAge.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
averagesByAge = averagesByAge.sortByKey()
results = averagesByAge.collect()
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Also in the spark ui

[image]

I did not deploy any other worker. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Ran into the same error. Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @Pete - From what I investigated is just a warning that should be ignored, and the job runs successfully.